# Bright Color Escape Sequences not saved in Tmux capture-pane?

Tags: tmux, colors, buffer

I'm trying to use tmux to create a pty for me that I can read the contents of, including color. I'm using  `tmux capture-pane -e -t paneName` and `tmux save-buffer tmuxbuffer.txt` and I get normal colors, bright colors, normal highlights, but the bright highlights in the \033[100m to \033[107m range that I can see on the tmux session do not get output to the buffer, instead I get a \033[m with no code at all. Is this something wrong with tmux itself or am I missing something?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was fixed in https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/edca27ae45db7be104bc56a4e48e55cddc40acdb#diff-bcf60a6025d9d3ce75156241c2dc0a53. This might apply to 3.1b, or you could build from master or wait for 3.2.